# postfix courier mailserver does not create /home/vmail maildir but instead a file in /var/mail/

Tags: postfix, email-server, courier

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-11.10) to the letter.

However, after mailing a welcome message, postfix does not create a Maildir in `/home/vmail`. instead, it creates a file with the username in `/var/mail/`.

This is my error message in `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
May  1 20:57:04 h2025044 imapd: chdir herr-webdesign.de/alex/: No such file or directory
May  1 20:57:04 h2025044 imapd: alex@herr-webdesign.de: No such file or directory
```

and my postconf:

```
2bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
access_map_defer_code = 450
access_map_reject_code = 554
address_verify_cache_cleanup_interval = 12h
address_verify_default_transport = $default_transport
address_verify_local_transport = $local_transport
address_verify_map = btree:$data_directory/verify_cache
address_verify_negative_cache = yes
address_verify_negative_expire_time = 3d
address_verify_negative_refresh_time = 3h
address_verify_poll_count = ${stress?1}${stress:3}
address_verify_poll_delay = 3s
address_verify_positive_expire_time = 31d
address_verify_positive_refresh_time = 7d
address_verify_relay_transport = $relay_transport
address_verify_relayhost = $relayhost
address_verify_sender = $double_bounce_sender
address_verify_sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = $sender_dependent_default_transport_maps
address_verify_sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
address_verify_service_name = verify
address_verify_transport_maps = $transport_maps
address_verify_virtual_transport = $virtual_transport
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_mail_to_commands = alias, forward
allow_mail_to_files = alias, forward
allow_min_user = no
allow_percent_hack = yes
allow_untrusted_routing = no
alternate_config_directories = 
always_add_missing_headers = no
always_bcc = 
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
anvil_status_update_time = 600s
append_at_myorigin = yes
append_dot_mydomain = no
application_event_drain_time = 100s
authorized_flush_users = static:anyone
authorized_mailq_users = static:anyone
authorized_submit_users = static:anyone
backwards_bounce_logfile_compatibility = yes
berkeley_db_create_buffer_size = 16777216
berkeley_db_read_buffer_size = 131072
best_mx_transport = 
biff = no
body_checks = 
body_checks_size_limit = 51200
bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
bounce_queue_lifetime = 5d
bounce_service_name = bounce
bounce_size_limit = 50000
bounce_template_file = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
canonical_classes = envelope_sender, envelope_recipient, header_sender, header_recipient
canonical_maps = 
cleanup_service_name = cleanup
command_directory = /usr/sbin
command_execution_directory = 
command_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
command_time_limit = 1000s
config_directory = /etc/postfix
connection_cache_protocol_timeout = 5s
connection_cache_service_name = scache
connection_cache_status_update_time = 600s
connection_cache_ttl_limit = 2s
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
cyrus_sasl_config_path = 
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
daemon_timeout = 18000s
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 
default_database_type = hash
default_delivery_slot_cost = 5
default_delivery_slot_discount = 50
default_delivery_slot_loan = 3
default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = 1
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20
default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = 1
default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = 1
default_destination_rate_delay = 0s
default_destination_recipient_limit = 50
default_extra_recipient_limit = 1000
default_filter_nexthop = 
default_minimum_delivery_slots = 3
default_privs = nobody
default_process_limit = 100
default_rbl_reply = $rbl_code Service unavailable; $rbl_class [$rbl_what] blocked using $rbl_domain${rbl_reason?; $rbl_reason}
default_recipient_limit = 20000
default_recipient_refill_delay = 5s
default_recipient_refill_limit = 100
default_transport = smtp
default_verp_delimiters = +=
defer_code = 450
defer_service_name = defer
defer_transports = 
delay_logging_resolution_limit = 2
delay_notice_recipient = postmaster
delay_warning_time = 0h
deliver_lock_attempts = 20
deliver_lock_delay = 1s
destination_concurrency_feedback_debug = no
detect_8bit_encoding_header = yes
disable_dns_lookups = no
disable_mime_input_processing = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
disable_verp_bounces = no
disable_vrfy_command = no
dont_remove = 0
double_bounce_sender = double-bounce
duplicate_filter_limit = 1000
empty_address_default_transport_maps_lookup_key = <>
empty_address_recipient = MAILER-DAEMON
empty_address_relayhost_maps_lookup_key = <>
enable_original_recipient = yes
error_notice_recipient = postmaster
error_service_name = error
execution_directory_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
expand_owner_alias = no
export_environment = TZ MAIL_CONFIG LANG
fallback_transport = 
fallback_transport_maps = 
fast_flush_domains = $relay_domains
fast_flush_purge_time = 7d
fast_flush_refresh_time = 12h
fault_injection_code = 0
flush_service_name = flush
fork_attempts = 5
fork_delay = 1s
forward_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
forward_path = $home/.forward${recipient_delimiter}${extension}, $home/.forward
frozen_delivered_to = yes
hash_queue_depth = 1
hash_queue_names = deferred, defer
header_address_token_limit = 10240
header_checks = 
header_size_limit = 102400
helpful_warnings = yes
home_mailbox = 
hopcount_limit = 50
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
ignore_mx_lookup_error = no
import_environment = MAIL_CONFIG MAIL_DEBUG MAIL_LOGTAG TZ XAUTHORITY DISPLAY LANG=C
in_flow_delay = 1s
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
initial_destination_concurrency = 5
internal_mail_filter_classes = 
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 501
ipc_idle = 5s
ipc_timeout = 3600s
ipc_ttl = 1000s
line_length_limit = 2048
lmtp_assume_final = no
lmtp_bind_address = 
lmtp_bind_address6 = 
lmtp_body_checks = 
lmtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
lmtp_connect_timeout = 0s
lmtp_connection_cache_destinations = 
lmtp_connection_cache_on_demand = yes
lmtp_connection_cache_time_limit = 2s
lmtp_connection_reuse_time_limit = 300s
lmtp_data_done_timeout = 600s
lmtp_data_init_timeout = 120s
lmtp_data_xfer_timeout = 180s
lmtp_defer_if_no_mx_address_found = no
lmtp_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
lmtp_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
lmtp_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
lmtp_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
lmtp_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
lmtp_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
lmtp_discard_lhlo_keyword_address_maps = 
lmtp_discard_lhlo_keywords = 
lmtp_enforce_tls = no
lmtp_generic_maps = 
lmtp_header_checks = 
lmtp_host_lookup = dns
lmtp_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
lmtp_lhlo_name = $myhostname
lmtp_lhlo_timeout = 300s
lmtp_line_length_limit = 990
lmtp_mail_timeout = 300s
lmtp_mime_header_checks = 
lmtp_mx_address_limit = 5
lmtp_mx_session_limit = 2
lmtp_nested_header_checks = 
lmtp_pix_workaround_delay_time = 10s
lmtp_pix_workaround_maps = 
lmtp_pix_workaround_threshold_time = 500s
lmtp_pix_workarounds = disable_esmtp,delay_dotcrlf
lmtp_quit_timeout = 300s
lmtp_quote_rfc821_envelope = yes
lmtp_randomize_addresses = yes
lmtp_rcpt_timeout = 300s
lmtp_reply_filter = 
lmtp_rset_timeout = 20s
lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name = 
lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_time = 90d
lmtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
lmtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
lmtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = 
lmtp_sasl_password_maps = 
lmtp_sasl_path = 
lmtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
lmtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $lmtp_sasl_security_options
lmtp_sasl_tls_verified_security_options = $lmtp_sasl_tls_security_options
lmtp_sasl_type = cyrus
lmtp_send_xforward_command = no
lmtp_sender_dependent_authentication = no
lmtp_skip_5xx_greeting = yes
lmtp_skip_quit_response = no
lmtp_starttls_timeout = 300s
lmtp_tcp_port = 24
lmtp_tls_CAfile = 
lmtp_tls_CApath = 
lmtp_tls_block_early_mail_reply = no
lmtp_tls_cert_file = 
lmtp_tls_ciphers = export
lmtp_tls_dcert_file = 
lmtp_tls_dkey_file = $lmtp_tls_dcert_file
lmtp_tls_eccert_file = 
lmtp_tls_eckey_file = $lmtp_tls_eccert_file
lmtp_tls_enforce_peername = yes
lmtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = 
lmtp_tls_fingerprint_cert_match = 
lmtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
lmtp_tls_key_file = $lmtp_tls_cert_file
lmtp_tls_loglevel = 0
lmtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
lmtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = 
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
lmtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = no
lmtp_tls_per_site = 
lmtp_tls_policy_maps = 
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2
lmtp_tls_scert_verifydepth = 9
lmtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop
lmtp_tls_security_level = 
lmtp_tls_session_cache_database = 
lmtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
lmtp_tls_verify_cert_match = hostname
lmtp_use_tls = no
lmtp_xforward_timeout = 300s
local_command_shell = 
local_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
local_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
local_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
local_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
local_destination_recipient_limit = 1
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_inet_interfaces
local_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
local_transport = local:$myhostname
luser_relay = 
mail_name = Postfix
mail_owner = postfix
mail_release_date = 20100213
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
mail_version = 2.7.0
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_command_maps = 
mailbox_delivery_lock = fcntl, dotlock
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = 
mailbox_transport_maps = 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
maps_rbl_domains = 
maps_rbl_reject_code = 554
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains = 
masquerade_exceptions = 
master_service_disable = 
max_idle = 100s
max_use = 100
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 5d
message_reject_characters = 
message_size_limit = 10240000
message_strip_characters = 
milter_command_timeout = 30s
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v
milter_connect_timeout = 30s
milter_content_timeout = 300s
milter_data_macros = i
milter_default_action = tempfail
milter_end_of_data_macros = i
milter_end_of_header_macros = i
milter_header_checks = 
milter_helo_macros = {tls_version} {cipher} {cipher_bits} {cert_subject} {cert_issuer}
milter_macro_daemon_name = $myhostname
milter_macro_v = $mail_name $mail_version
milter_mail_macros = i {auth_type} {auth_authen} {auth_author} {mail_addr} {mail_host} {mail_mailer}
milter_protocol = 6
milter_rcpt_macros = i {rcpt_addr} {rcpt_host} {rcpt_mailer}
milter_unknown_command_macros = 
mime_boundary_length_limit = 2048
mime_header_checks = $header_checks
mime_nesting_limit = 100
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
multi_instance_directories = 
multi_instance_enable = no
multi_instance_group = 
multi_instance_name = 
multi_instance_wrapper = 
multi_recipient_bounce_reject_code = 550
mydestination = herr-webdesign.de, localhost, localhost.localdomain
mydomain = localdomain
myhostname = herr-webdesign.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = /etc/mailname
nested_header_checks = $header_checks
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
non_fqdn_reject_code = 504
non_smtpd_milters = 
notify_classes = resource, software
owner_request_special = yes
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,smtpd_access_maps
permit_mx_backup_networks = 
pickup_service_name = pickup
plaintext_reject_code = 450
postmulti_control_commands = reload flush
postmulti_start_commands = start
postmulti_stop_commands = stop abort drain quick-stop
prepend_delivered_header = command, file, forward
process_id_directory = pid
propagate_unmatched_extensions = canonical, virtual
proxy_interfaces = 
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
proxy_write_maps = $smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name $lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name
proxymap_service_name = proxymap
proxywrite_service_name = proxywrite
qmgr_clog_warn_time = 300s
qmgr_fudge_factor = 100
qmgr_message_active_limit = 20000
qmgr_message_recipient_limit = 20000
qmgr_message_recipient_minimum = 10
qmqpd_authorized_clients = 
qmqpd_client_port_logging = no
qmqpd_error_delay = 1s
qmqpd_timeout = 300s
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
queue_file_attribute_count_limit = 100
queue_minfree = 0
queue_run_delay = 300s
queue_service_name = qmgr
rbl_reply_maps = 
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_bcc_maps = 
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient, header_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps = 
recipient_delimiter = +
reject_code = 554
reject_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
relay_clientcerts = 
relay_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
relay_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
relay_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
relay_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
relay_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
relay_domains = $mydestination
relay_domains_reject_code = 554
relay_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
relay_recipient_maps = 
relay_transport = relay
relayhost = 
relocated_maps = 
remote_header_rewrite_domain = 
require_home_directory = no
resolve_dequoted_address = yes
resolve_null_domain = no
resolve_numeric_domain = no
rewrite_service_name = rewrite
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
send_cyrus_sasl_authzid = no
sender_bcc_maps = 
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender
sender_canonical_maps = 
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = 
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = 
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
service_throttle_time = 60s
setgid_group = postdrop
show_user_unknown_table_name = yes
showq_service_name = showq
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_bind_address = 
smtp_bind_address6 = 
smtp_body_checks = 
smtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
smtp_connect_timeout = 30s
smtp_connection_cache_destinations = 
smtp_connection_cache_on_demand = yes
smtp_connection_cache_time_limit = 2s
smtp_connection_reuse_time_limit = 300s
smtp_data_done_timeout = 600s
smtp_data_init_timeout = 120s
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 180s
smtp_defer_if_no_mx_address_found = no
smtp_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
smtp_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
smtp_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
smtp_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
smtp_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
smtp_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps = 
smtp_discard_ehlo_keywords = 
smtp_enforce_tls = no
smtp_fallback_relay = $fallback_relay
smtp_generic_maps = 
smtp_header_checks = 
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
smtp_helo_timeout = 300s
smtp_host_lookup = dns
smtp_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
smtp_line_length_limit = 990
smtp_mail_timeout = 300s
smtp_mime_header_checks = 
smtp_mx_address_limit = 5
smtp_mx_session_limit = 2
smtp_nested_header_checks = 
smtp_never_send_ehlo = no
smtp_pix_workaround_delay_time = 10s
smtp_pix_workaround_maps = 
smtp_pix_workaround_threshold_time = 500s
smtp_pix_workarounds = disable_esmtp,delay_dotcrlf
smtp_quit_timeout = 300s
smtp_quote_rfc821_envelope = yes
smtp_randomize_addresses = yes
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 300s
smtp_reply_filter = 
smtp_rset_timeout = 20s
smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name = 
smtp_sasl_auth_cache_time = 90d
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = 
smtp_sasl_path = 
smtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtp_sasl_security_options
smtp_sasl_tls_verified_security_options = $smtp_sasl_tls_security_options
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_send_xforward_command = no
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = no
smtp_skip_5xx_greeting = yes
smtp_skip_quit_response = yes
smtp_starttls_timeout = 300s
smtp_tls_CAfile = 
smtp_tls_CApath = 
smtp_tls_block_early_mail_reply = no
smtp_tls_cert_file = 
smtp_tls_ciphers = export
smtp_tls_dcert_file = 
smtp_tls_dkey_file = $smtp_tls_dcert_file
smtp_tls_eccert_file = 
smtp_tls_eckey_file = $smtp_tls_eccert_file
smtp_tls_enforce_peername = yes
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = 
smtp_tls_fingerprint_cert_match = 
smtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
smtp_tls_key_file = $smtp_tls_cert_file
smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = 
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = no
smtp_tls_per_site = 
smtp_tls_policy_maps = 
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2
smtp_tls_scert_verifydepth = 9
smtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop, dot-nexthop
smtp_tls_security_level = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtp_tls_verify_cert_match = hostname
smtp_use_tls = no
smtp_xforward_timeout = 300s
smtpd_authorized_verp_clients = $authorized_verp_clients
smtpd_authorized_xclient_hosts = 
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 50
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions = ${smtpd_client_connection_limit_exceptions:$mynetworks}
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_port_logging = no
smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
smtpd_command_filter = 
smtpd_data_restrictions = 
smtpd_delay_open_until_valid_rcpt = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps = 
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords = 
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = 
smtpd_enforce_tls = no
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_etrn_restrictions = 
smtpd_expansion_filter = \t\40!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
smtpd_forbidden_commands = CONNECT GET POST
smtpd_hard_error_limit = ${stress?1}${stress:20}
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions = 
smtpd_history_flush_threshold = 100
smtpd_junk_command_limit = ${stress?1}${stress:100}
smtpd_milters = 
smtpd_noop_commands = 
smtpd_null_access_lookup_key = <>
smtpd_peername_lookup = yes
smtpd_policy_service_max_idle = 300s
smtpd_policy_service_max_ttl = 1000s
smtpd_policy_service_timeout = 100s
smtpd_proxy_ehlo = $myhostname
smtpd_proxy_filter = 
smtpd_proxy_options = 
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 100s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_overshoot_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
smtpd_restriction_classes = 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = 
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sender_login_maps = 
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_starttls_timeout = 300s
smtpd_timeout = ${stress?10}${stress:300}s
smtpd_tls_CAfile = 
smtpd_tls_CApath = 
smtpd_tls_always_issue_session_ids = yes
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_ccert_verifydepth = 9
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_ciphers = export
smtpd_tls_dcert_file = 
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = 
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = 
smtpd_tls_dkey_file = $smtpd_tls_dcert_file
smtpd_tls_eccert_file = 
smtpd_tls_eckey_file = $smtpd_tls_eccert_file
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = none
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = 
smtpd_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = 
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_protocols = 
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_tls_req_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_security_level = 
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_wrappermode = no
smtpd_use_tls = yes
soft_bounce = no
stale_lock_time = 500s
stress = 
strict_7bit_headers = no
strict_8bitmime = no
strict_8bitmime_body = no
strict_mailbox_ownership = yes
strict_mime_encoding_domain = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
sun_mailtool_compatibility = no
swap_bangpath = yes
syslog_facility = mail
syslog_name = ${multi_instance_name:postfix}${multi_instance_name?$multi_instance_name}
tcp_windowsize = 0
tls_daemon_random_bytes = 32
tls_eecdh_strong_curve = prime256v1
tls_eecdh_ultra_curve = secp384r1
tls_export_cipherlist = ALL:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_high_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:!LOW:!MEDIUM:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_low_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_medium_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:!LOW:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_null_cipherlist = eNULL:!aNULL
tls_random_bytes = 32
tls_random_exchange_name = ${data_directory}/prng_exch
tls_random_prng_update_period = 3600s
tls_random_reseed_period = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
trace_service_name = trace
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
transport_retry_time = 60s
trigger_timeout = 10s
undisclosed_recipients_header = To: undisclosed-recipients:;
unknown_address_reject_code = 450
unknown_address_tempfail_action = $reject_tempfail_action
unknown_client_reject_code = 450
unknown_helo_hostname_tempfail_action = $reject_tempfail_action
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 450
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unknown_relay_recipient_reject_code = 550
unknown_virtual_alias_reject_code = 550
unknown_virtual_mailbox_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_defer_code = 450
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 450
unverified_recipient_reject_reason = 
unverified_recipient_tempfail_action = $reject_tempfail_action
unverified_sender_defer_code = 450
unverified_sender_reject_code = 450
unverified_sender_reject_reason = 
unverified_sender_tempfail_action = $reject_tempfail_action
verp_delimiter_filter = -=+
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_expansion_limit = 1000
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_alias_recursion_limit = 1000
virtual_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
virtual_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
virtual_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
virtual_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
virtual_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
virtual_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_limit_inbox = no
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_mailbox_lock = fcntl, dotlock
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
virtual_maildir_filter = no
virtual_maildir_filter_maps = 
virtual_maildir_limit_message = Sorry, the user's maildir has overdrawn his diskspace quota, please try again later.
virtual_maildir_limit_message_maps = 
virtual_maildir_suffix = 
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_trash_count = no
virtual_trash_name = .Trash
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Comment: It might be that the virtual domain is not defined in the mysql table it should be.  However, to give a more useful answer than that I'd need to see your complete configuration.

Comment: hi @FalconKirtaran The domain in question is the local domain, so I actually had to remove it from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command and check that you've set the virtual_mailbox_base correctly.

```
postconf -n | grep vmail
```

Assuming that setting is correct send the user in question an email. Postfix is the daemon that creates the maildir which is done when the first mail is delivered. From your logs it looks like the imap daemon is complaining that the dir doesn't exist which makes sense.

Edit:

Looks like the domain you're talking about is **not virtual**. Therefore it's going to go where ever Postfix normally put it and not in `/var/vmail/`

---

FWIW, I'd use a how-to based around Postfixadmin to manage the server instead phpmyamdin. Switching over would involve tossing out the current db schema and starting from scratch. However it's a much better system *and* Postfixadmin sends welcome messages to new accounts when you create them as well as other useful features.

Comment: hi kashani! As you can see from my postconf, the virtual_mailbox_base is indeed set to /home/vmail. Is it maybe the mail_spool_directory that's causing the trouble?

Comment: Two things. No one wants or needs to see you whole config file. Change it to only the output of postconf -n. Second, did you send the user an email as I suggested?

Comment: Looks like the domain you're talkign about is not virtual. Therefore it's going to go where ever Postfix normally put it and not in /var/vmail/

Answer (score 0):

Postfix isn't responsible for creating the Maildirs, courier is, and it won't do on it's own, you have to type in the commands.

Here's an example script that will create the given mailbox and set a 1Gb quota to it :

```
root@messagerie-secours[10.10.10.19] ~/SCRIPTS/MAIL # cat ./createmailbox.courier.single


if [ "$#" = 0 ]
then
    echo "usage : $0 boite@domain.com"
    exit 1
fi



inbox="${1%@*}"
domain="${1#*@}"
maildir=/var/vmail/"$domain"/"$inbox"
quota=$((1024*1024*1024)) # 1Go


function create_mailbox {
    local dst="$1"

# Création de la boite
    echo maildirmake.courier -S  "$dst"
    maildirmake.courier -S  "$dst"
# Installation du quota
    echo maildirmake.courier -q "$quota" S "$dst"
    maildirmake.courier -q "$quota"S "$dst"
# Permissions de fichiers
    echo chown vmail:vmail -R "$dst"
    chown vmail:vmail -R "$dst"
}

if ! test -e "$maildir"
then
    create_mailbox "$maildir" "$domain"
else
    echo maildir "$maildir" exists, aborting.
fi
root@messagerie-secours[10.10.10.19] ~/SCRIPTS/MAIL #
```